# Can't set confirmationHandler on a connection with confirmation-window-size < 0 error when deployBridge with DEFAULT_CONFIRMATION_WINDOW_SIZE(-1)

Tags: activemq-artemis

I try to deploy `Core Bridge` via `ActiveMQServer.deployBridge(BridgeConfiguration config)`, I create `BridgeConfiguration` with default value (DEFAULT_CONFIRMATION_WINDOW_SIZE = -1) for `confirmationWindowSize`

[image]

and put it in `ActiveMQServer.deployBridge(BridgeConfiguration config)`, but after that, I get the errors

> You can't set confirmationHandler on a connection with
> confirmation-window-size < 0. Look at the documentation for more
> information.

[image]

What am I doing wrong or is it a bug?

Artemis version 2.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a minor bug with the default value for `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.BridgeConfiguration#confirmationWindowSize`. Currently it is using this:

```java
private int confirmationWindowSize = ActiveMQClient.DEFAULT_CONFIRMATION_WINDOW_SIZE;
```

However, it should be using this:

```java
private int confirmationWindowSize = ActiveMQDefaultConfiguration.getDefaultBridgeConfirmationWindowSize();
```

You can work around this issue by setting the confirmation window size manually, e.g.:

```java
BridgeConfiguration myBridgeConfiguration = new BridgeConfiguration();
myBridgeConfiguration.setConfirmationWindowSize(ActiveMQDefaultConfiguration.getDefaultBridgeConfirmationWindowSize());
```

I opened [a Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3096) for this, sent [a PR](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/pull/3430), and the PR has been merged. The fix will appear in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0.

Comment: I created anothet task https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3099

Comment: I've sent [a PR](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/pull/3433) for that issue as well. Thanks for filing the issue!

Comment: Аnd another question. The bridge parameter `failover-on-server-shutdown` is described in the documentation, but I see it in the code only in the `artemis-configuration.xsd`, nowhere else, not in the `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.BridgeConfiguration`, etc. It turns out that it is useless and is not used anywhere else, should it be removed from the documentation?

Comment: As far as I can tell that documentation should be removed and the XSD should also be updated. Feel free to open a Jira. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I sent [a PR](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/pull/3437) for the doc/xsd issue.